# Poor performance (low requests per second and high response time) using Gunicorn + FastAPI + Machine learning model on AWS Fargate

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fastapi, gunicorn, aws-fargate

I'm deploying an ML model that takes as input a string and provides a set of numeric values determining the toxicity of the string. The model I'm using is [Detoxify](https://github.com/unitaryai/detoxify) running on CPU as Fargate does not yet support GPU instances.

Despite using gunicorn with 3 workers + FastAPI + preloading the model into a Docker image and then deploying to an instance on AWS Fargate (4 x vCPU / 8Gb RAM) behind an Application Load Balancer I'm experiencing poor requests per second performance (**max ~25 req/second / 8sec response time**). By comparison, load testing the **`/healthcheck` endpoint achieves around 3.8k req per/sec**.

I'm load testing using [Locust](https://locust.io/) to send requests to the api deployed on AWS.

I have the following FastApi server:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from detoxify import Detoxify

app = FastAPI()

model = Detoxify("unbiased-small", device="cpu")

@app.get("/healthcheck")
def healthcheck():
    return { "status": "OK" }

@app.get("/healthcheck/loadbalancer")
def healthcheck():
    return { "status": "OK" }

@app.get("/toxicity")
def predict(q: str):
    try:
      return model.predict([q])
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=str(e))
```

I'm running gunicorn using the following dockerfile command:

```bash
CMD gunicorn app.server:app --workers 3 --preload --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --keep-alive 10
```

There seems to be an issue when I scale up the number of connected clients attempting to make requests (i.e. 100 clients causes a higher response time of 8secs and achieves 20 req/sec vs 10 clients with 700ms response time but still achiving 20 req/sec).

Comment: Obviously an API call that does actual work, using a machine learning model on a CPU (no GPU available) is going to be less scalable than a `/healthcheck` call that does nothing. Stating that your `/healthcheck` call can handle more requests doesn't really prove anything. What you need to be looking at is the actual CPU usage of your Fargate task during this test. If the CPU usage is maxing out, then that is all the requests you will be able to handle.

Comment: The CPU is maxing out. I've started looking at AWS Neuron to try and optimize the model for AWS Inferentia EC2 instances to improve throughput. https://awsdocs-neuron.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/index.html

Comment: So it sounds like it is working as expected and there really isn't a question to answer here.

Comment: @Garbit ; I do end up with the same problem. Any solutions found?